# React/RCTConvert.h file not found with ReactNativeNavigation ver3

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm bilding mobile app the following technologies.

```
react-native: v0.60.0
react-native-navigation: 3.0.0-alpha.2
```

And I build this app for iOS, then the following error message appears in the ReactNativeNavigation code.

```
React/RCTConvert.h file not found
```

The error file is `Pods/Development Pods/ReactNativeNavigation/RNNOptions.h`, and this is the content of it.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <React/RCTConvert.h>
#import "BoolParser.h"
#import "TextParser.h"
#import "NumberParser.h"
#import "DictionaryParser.h"
#import "ColorParser.h"
#import "ImageParser.h"
#import "IntNumberParser.h"
#import "DoubleParser.h"

@interface RNNOptions : NSObject

- (instancetype)initWithDict:(NSDictionary*)dict;

- (RNNOptions *)overrideOptions:(RNNOptions *)otherOptions;
- (RNNOptions *)mergeOptions:(RNNOptions *)otherOptions;
- (RNNOptions *)mergeInOptions:(RNNOptions *)otherOptions;

- (RNNOptions *)withDefault:(RNNOptions *)defaultOptions;

@end
```

I have already tried,

- Following this [tutorial](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/docs/Installing?id=ios)

But it didn't work well, so I additionally tried these.

- Insert `pod 'ReactNativeNavigation', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-navigation'` into `ios/Podfile`.
- Run `react-native link react-native-navigation` and `pod install` in `ios` directory
- Clean and rebuild the proejct in Xcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with react native 0.60+ you don't need to link react native navigation manually.

simply run `react-native link react-native-navigation` and `cd ios; pod install`

for more information please see this [issue](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/5258)

Comment: what about react native 0.59